# Update column in one table for a user based on count of required records in another table for same user without cursor

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables `A and B`. I need to update a column in `table A` for all userid's based on the count of records that `userid` has in another table based on defined rules. If `count` of records in another table is 3 and is required for that `userID`, then mark `IsCorrect` as 1 else 0, if `count` is 2 and required is 5 then `IsCorrect` as 0 For e.g. Below is what I am trying to achieve

Table A

```
UserID |  Required  |  IsCorrect
----------------------------------
1      |     SO;GO;PE       |     1
2      |     SO;GO;PE;PR    |     0
3      |     SO;GO;PE       |     1
```

Table B

```
UserID  |  PPName
-----------------------   
1     |     SO
1     |     GO
1     |     PE
2     |     SO
2     |     GO
3     |     SO
3     |     GO
3     |     PE
```

I tried using Update in table joining another table, but cannot up with one. Also, do not want to use cursors, because of its overhead. I know I will have to create a stored Procedure for it for the rules, but how to pass the userID's to it without cursor is what am i am looking for.

This is an update for my earlier question. Thanks for the help.

Comment: your dbms name please?

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server 2016. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use `sub-query` and aggregate function and then case when for conditional update

```
update TableA A 
set A.IsCorrect= case when T.cnt>=3 then 1 else 0 end 
inner join 
(
select B.UserID ,count(*) as cnt from TableB as B
    group by UserID  
) as T
on A.userid=T.UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for PostgreSQL:

```
update TableA
set IsCorrect =
  case when
    string_to_array(Required, ';') <@
    (select array_agg(PPName)
     from TableB
     where TableA.UserID = TableB.UserID)
      then 1
      else 0
  end;
```

You can also see it [live on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/69777/4).